# Looking for a tool similar to the Security Advisor plugin for WHM that can run on CentOS 7 without WHM

Tags: security, scanner, vulnerability

The startup I'm working at is setting up some new CentOS 7 servers that will host a mobile application, and some of the data is sensitive, thus, the servers need to be secured to the best of our ability.

I installed Snort for an IDS, but I also wanted to install something that would basically audit the settings/configurations on the server for any vulnerabilities or attack vectors. Something similar to [Security Advisor](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Security+Center) or the [report generated by CSF](http://configserver.com/cp/csfdemo/report.html), except since we don't use cPanel/WHM, it needs to be able to run as an independent service/application.

Does anyone know of a tool like this? I know something like Nexpose can do this, also checking versions and security eratta, but that may be overkill for a couple of servers.

Thanks!

P.S. Just to clarify, I'm not looking for a firewall or anything to modify the configuration settings, I just need the audit capabilities.

P.S.S. Also, I was planning on having the audit/scan automatically run every so often, just to detect if there were any changes. So if there's anything that could send out any "critical" results, after an audit, then that would be great. I found something called [Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/), and I'm looking at that, but there's probably something better than this.